# Azure - Cannot add Microsoft account to Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I used to be able to add a Microsoft account (more specific: a hotmail account) to an Azure Subscription. But now I cannot add another Microsoft account to my Azure Subscription.

[image: Add role assignment]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the account existing in your azure ad tenant?

Comment: Hello Joy Wang,
The MS account is certain dependent account, not in Azure ad tenant
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing this because the account does not exist in the Azure AD tenant. To solve the issue:

- Go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com)
- Navigate to `Azure Active Directory`
- Navigate to `Users`
- Navigate to `New Guest User`
- Invite the Microsoft account to your tenant

Don't forget to accept the invitation email for the account, then you should be able to assign a role just fine.

Answer (score 0):

My tenant is normal account, not admin.
I used to invite MS account by:
 - Go Subscription
 - Access control (IAM)
 - Add role assignment 
As below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YThqy.png) 
But now I cannot do that again